# r ggplot how to iteratively plot across all character variables in a df and plot them in the grid structure dynamically

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2

```
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)
library(tidyquant) # theme_tq()
library(ggplot2)
```

i have the following data:

```
head(training,20)
   gender_dom marital     race edu_level rental inc_level cluster_Kproto
1           F  single   others jrcollege rented      high              1
2           M married hispanic  postgrad leased    medium              3
3           M   other hispanic  highschl rented      high              1
6           M   other hispanic  postgrad rented    medium              3
7           M married    black doctorate leased    medium              3
8           M married hispanic jrcollege  owned      high              2
10          F  single   others  graduate rented       low              3
12          F married    asian  highschl  owned    medium              3
14          M  single hispanic  graduate leased      high              1
16          F married    white  postgrad rented    medium              3
18          M   other   others  postgrad leased    medium              3
22          F  single   others  graduate leased      high              2
23          M  single    asian doctorate leased    medium              3
25          F   other    white  highschl rented    medium              3
26          M   other    asian jrcollege leased       low              3
27          F  single    white jrcollege leased    medium              3
28          M married    asian doctorate rented       low              3
29          F   other    white  highschl rented      high              1
30          F  single hispanic jrcollege leased      high              2
31          F   other    asian jrcollege  owned       low              3

# Make variables into factors
factor_vars <- c('gender_dom','marital','race','edu_level','rental','inc_level','cluster_Kproto')
training[factor_vars] <- lapply(training[factor_vars], function(x) as.factor(x))
str(training)

library(tidyquant) # theme_tq()
par(ask=F) # to remove hit enter for each plot

(p1 <- training %>% ggplot(aes(x = race, fill = cluster_Kproto)) + geom_bar(position = position_dodge(width = 0.8), 
    width = 0.7, alpha = 0.8) + scale_fill_manual(values = palette_light()) + 
    theme_tq() + theme(legend.position = "right") + guides(fill = guide_legend("Cluster")) + 
    ggtitle("Cluster Distribution by Race") + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + 
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust = 1)) + 
    labs(x = "", fill = ""))

(p2 <- training %>% ggplot(aes(x = edu_level, fill = cluster_Kproto)) + geom_bar(position = position_dodge(width = 0.8), 
    width = 0.7, alpha = 0.8) + scale_fill_manual(values = palette_light()) + 
    theme_tq() + theme(legend.position = "right") + guides(fill = guide_legend("Cluster")) + 
    ggtitle("Cluster Distribution by Education level") + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + 
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust = 1)) + 
    labs(x = "", fill = ""))

(p3 <- training %>% ggplot(aes(x = marital, fill = cluster_Kproto)) + geom_bar(position = position_dodge(width = 0.8), 
    width = 0.7, alpha = 0.8) + scale_fill_manual(values = palette_light()) + 
    theme_tq() + theme(legend.position = "right") + guides(fill = guide_legend("Cluster")) + 
    ggtitle("Cluster Distribution by Marital") + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + 
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust = 1)) + 
    labs(x = "", fill = ""))

grid.arrange(p1, p2,p3,ncol = 2,nrow=2)
```

[image]

What i would like to do is plot all of the categorical var by `cluster_kproto` as done for few var in the above plot iteratively including the plot title also coming dynamically from the  x values of ggplot function  and all are grid arranged so that if my no of categorical var change, still i get grid arranged plot without the need of doing manual plotting for each categorical var as i was doing uptill now.

Need some assistance here!!!!!

Comment: wow - your last sentence sounds very urgent!!!!! :-) if you could post your data in a more copy-pastable format so that we can easily get it into R it would be much easier to help you and test our proposals (see `dput`). Otherwise as far as i understood - i think you are doing pretty well - you just need to extract your plot code into a fun. Then extract all factor var colnames from data and apply plot fun to them. Remember that you need to quote the `x` var name that gets passed into the plotting function. Then it's a matter of your choice how you display the plots (grid, export to pdf...)

Comment: I think you can use facetting for this instead of creating 3 independent plots. Then you wrap your code into a function that would get the name of a column to plot and appropriately update the faceting and the title of the plot.

Comment: By the way, you'd better illustrate your point on standard datasets in the future (e.g. mtcars, iris, diamonds, etc.) and provide MWE which contains *just the bare minimum*. It makes so much easier to reproduce your efforts!

Comment: @ R Kiselev   will repost wit `mtcars` dataset asap.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create custom function `plotMyData` and just loop over the variables you want to plot:

```
plotMyData <- function(varName, inputData) {
    ggplot(inputData, aes(x = get(varName), fill = cluster_Kproto)) + 
        geom_bar(position = position_dodge(width = 0.8), 
                 width = 0.7, alpha = 0.8) + 
        scale_fill_manual(values = palette_light()) + 
        ggtitle(paste("Cluster Distribution by", varName)) + 
        labs(x = "", fill = "") +
        guides(fill = guide_legend("Cluster")) + 
        theme_tq() + 
        theme(legend.position = "right") + 
        theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + 
        theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust = 1))
}

plotList <- list()
varToPlot <- c("race", "edu_level", "marital")

for(i in varToPlot) {
    plotList[[i]] <- plotMyData(i, training)
}
do.call("grid.arrange", c(plotList, ncol = 2, nrow = 2))
```

Comment: @Nishant happy to help! :-)

Comment: Making it more dynamic:   `plotList <- list() varToPlot <- names(training[-7]) for(i in varToPlot) { plotList[[i]] <- plotMyData(i, training) } do.call("grid.arrange", c(plotList, ncol = 2, nrow = ceiling(length(varToPlot)/2))`